# Kali Linux bluetooth issue: can't find bluetooth in my PC

Tags: kali-linux, bluetooth

```
┌──(rootkali)-[/home/subash]
└─# service bluetooth status                                                                                                                                      1 ⨯
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2021-01-20 10:50:32 IST; 5min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 656 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 4371)
     Memory: 2.9M
        CPU: 16ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─656 /usr/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Jan 20 10:50:32 kali bluetoothd[656]: src/main.c:parse_controller_config() Key file does not have key “LEScanIntervalConnect” in group “Controller”
Jan 20 10:50:32 kali bluetoothd[656]: src/main.c:parse_controller_config() Key file does not have key “LEScanWindowConnect” in group “Controller”
Jan 20 10:50:32 kali bluetoothd[656]: src/main.c:parse_controller_config() Key file does not have key “LEMinConnectionInterval” in group “Controller”
Jan 20 10:50:32 kali bluetoothd[656]: src/main.c:parse_controller_config() Key file does not have key “LEMaxConnectionInterval” in group “Controller”
Jan 20 10:50:32 kali bluetoothd[656]: src/main.c:parse_controller_config() Key file does not have key “LEConnectionLatency” in group “Controller”
Jan 20 10:50:32 kali bluetoothd[656]: src/main.c:parse_controller_config() Key file does not have key “LEConnectionSupervisionTimeout” in group “Controller”
Jan 20 10:50:32 kali bluetoothd[656]: src/main.c:parse_controller_config() Key file does not have key “LEAutoconnecttimeout” in group “Controller”
Jan 20 10:50:32 kali systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Jan 20 10:50:32 kali bluetoothd[656]: Starting SDP server
Jan 20 10:50:32 kali bluetoothd[656]: Bluetooth management interface 1.18 initialized
```

`lsusb` shows

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05c8:03d2 Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink) HP TrueVision HD Camera
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0513:0318 digital-X, Inc.
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:b00c Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Bluetooth Radio
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Answer (score 1):

By the `lsusb` output in the question comments, you have a Bluetooth radio chip from Realtek.

Realtek's Bluetooth radios will need a firmware file to work correctly. Make sure the `firmware-realtek` package is installed: run `apt install firmware-realtek`.

If it reports that the package is already installed, run `dmesg | grep firmware` and see if you can find a message similar to this (the name of the actual firmware file may be different):

```
bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for rtl_bt/rtl8761a_config.bin failed with error -2
```

This will indicate the name of the missing firmware file. In this example, the firmware file required by the driver was `/lib/firmware/rtl_bt/rtl8761a_config.bin`.

If the file required to run *your* Bluetooth radio chip is not included in the `firmware-realtek` package, download it from [`rtl_bt` directory of the linux-firmware repository](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/rtl_bt), and place it to `/lib/firmware/rtl_bt/` directory on your system.

Once the firmware file has been installed (either by installing the `firmware-realtek` package, or by manually downloading the correct firmware file), just reboot your system and your Bluetooth radio chip should now start working.

(If you find you need to download the file manually, check again after downloading the first file: some chips apparently need more than one firmware file.)